# import modules in python

Tags: python

when i write import win32print in my python command line (IDLE) it works fine and it is imported...
but when i write import win32print in my py file then it gives an error
says no module named win32print

why am i not able to load the module when writing the same statement in a py script...im using windows XP

Comment: It looks like `win32print` is not installed when you run your .py file, but it is from IDLE. Is your path to Python using a different Python installation?

Comment: yes that exactly was the problem...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check if you are running on the same installation. I'd do that by looking the path:

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

And compare the output on IDLE and when you run the .py

Comment: thank you...i was actually running python 2.6 on idle and 2.5 to compile my script...